# MongoDB Update Query with Multiple entries

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get an output like this:

```
> "expires" : {
>                 "date" : 30,
>                 "year" : 2017,
>                 "month" : 6
>         },
```

My Code looks like this:

```
..update({ID:1},($set: {expires: {year: 2017, month : 6, date: 30}}))
```

I am not getting the desired output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your update part has incorrect syntax. Replace parenthesis with curly brackets like `update({ID:1},{$set: {expires: {year: 2017, month : 6, date: 30}}})`

Comment: i can't see full schema here, can you update your code

Comment: Thanks it worked